# Since we have [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:], why do we use [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

we can easily fetch simple web contents by codes below:

```
+ (NSString *)getContentWithURL:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(!data) {
        return @"";
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    }
}
```

but someone told me using NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are different things:

[dataWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC)

> This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects, and can also be used for reading short files synchronously. If you need to read potentially large files, use inputStreamWithURL: to open a stream, then read the file a piece at a time.
>
> **Important:** Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

[sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10)

> A synchronous load is built on top of the asynchronous loading code made available by the class. The calling thread is blocked while the asynchronous loading system performs the URL load on a thread spawned specifically for this load request. No special threading or run loop configuration is necessary in the calling thread in order to perform a synchronous load.
>
> **Important:** Because this call can potentially take several minutes to fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSURLConnection` way gives you more information about the response. If the request fails, with `NSData` you only get `nil` data and nothing else. With `NSURLConnection` you also get the HTTP response and an `NSError` to present to the user.

Comment: Method dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: can show error info

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` provides flexibility to run synchronous/asynchronous requests. Also using `NSURLConnection`, you can make the request with request type get/post/put etc while it snot possible for `dataWithContentsOfURL` method.

Answer (score 0):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous, which means that if you run it on the main thread the whole UI will lock up and the user will not be able to do *anything*; it will look as though your app has hung.

While *you* may be on a fast, reliable network, remember that many iPhone users are on unreliable and slow cellular networks. Or they may have a great signal and then drive into a tunnel. You should not assume that the network is available or fast. Synchronous network calls implicitly assume both.